# VBS or CMD file to move files into folders based on file name pattern matching

Tags: vbscript, cmd

Looking for some guidance...

I have a directory that regular receives files whos names contain the following info:

showname-episode-segment.mov

I'm looking for a method to move these files into directories that exist, named after the showname portion of the filename. In the event that a file exists that does not have that first hyphen delimiter it should be skipped. And in the event that a new show is introduced and the corresponding folder does not exist, it would get created.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

VBScript would probably be easiest. Here's a few snippets of how to do everything you'll need.

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' create a new folder
If Not fso.FolderExists(folderPath) Then
   Set newfolder = fso.CreateFolder(folderPath)
End If
' move a file
If fso.FileExists(filePathAndName) Then
   fso.MoveFile filePathAndName, folderPath
End If
' check file name
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)
Set files = folder.Files
For each file In files
    If InStr(file.Name, "-") > 0 Then
        'the file name has a "-" in it
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple batch file will do the trick. Define where you want to look for incoming files, and where you want the show folders created. Then use a simple FOR to list all incoming files that have the `*-*.mov` format. Use FOR /F to parse the show name (the text before the 1st `-`). Create the show folder if it doesn't exist, and then move the file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "incomingFolder=c:\video\incoming"
set "showsFolder=c:\video\shows"

for %%F in ("%incomingFolder%\*-*.mov") do (
  for /f "delims=-" %%A in ("%%~nF") do (
    if not exist "%showsFolder\%%A" md "%showsFolder%\%%A"
    move "%%F" "%showsFolder%\%%A"
  )
)
```